# How can I properly import this JSON file into pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is link used: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/prc_hicp_mmor?precision=1&geo=HU&geo=PL&geo=SK&unit=RCH_M&coicop=CP00
It has inflation data of 3 countries over a time period. This is my code so far:

```
import urllib.request, json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = r"http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/prc_hicp_mmor?precision=1&geo=HU&geo=PL&geo=SK&unit=RCH_M&coicop=CP00"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data))
print(df)
```

And this is the output, which is pretty far from what I would need...:
I need the HCIP of the 3 countries for each date mentioned in the JSON file.

```
 version                                              label  \
0     2.0  HICP (2015 = 100) - monthly data (monthly rate...   

                                                href    source     updated  \
0  http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2...  Eurostat  2021-08-31   

     class                         id            size status.0 status.1  ...  \
0  dataset  [unit, coicop, geo, time]  [1, 1, 3, 307]        d        d  ...   

  dimension.time.category.label.2020M11 dimension.time.category.label.2020M12  \
0                               2020M11                               2020M12   

  dimension.time.category.label.2021M01 dimension.time.category.label.2021M02  \
0                               2021M01                               2021M02   

  dimension.time.category.label.2021M03 dimension.time.category.label.2021M04  \
0                               2021M03                               2021M04   

  dimension.time.category.label.2021M05 dimension.time.category.label.2021M06  \
0                               2021M05                               2021M06   

  dimension.time.category.label.2021M07 dimension.time.category.label.2021M08  
0                               2021M07                               2021M08
```

Any idea what I did wrong? Or how could I import such a format properly?

Comment: what's the output you are expecting, please add that in your question

Comment: Are you sure you want to import the complete json response? I think its format is not compatible with your use case. Probably you just want `value` and `dimension.time.index` or `dimension.time.label`, which should be extracted before creating the `pd.DateFrame` .

Comment: @Chandan sorry, I edited it

Comment: @marcelh I don't really need everything. Thank you, I can try  that! Are these part of the request package, so I can look exact syntax up?

Comment: @JoshBob: Try to get the desired columns from `data` (e.g., `data['value']`) and use the list as your column.

Comment: @marcelh is it data['value'] because that's it's 'name' on the json file? So I can get data['geo'] for the country and data['time'] for the dates? Or I misunderstood it?

Comment: yes, you are right. `json.loads`wil return a Dictionary having `key`and `values` from the loaded json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand of your data:

- `data['id']` specifies the order of dimensions
- `data['dimension'][*]['category']` specifies the order of values per dimension
- `data['value']` are the raw values.

The rest seems to be redundant.

Now the easiest is to extract the values, let’s also make sure the index is correctly sorted:

```
>>> val = pd.Series(data['value']).rename(index=int).sort_index()
>>> val
0      2.4
1      1.6
2      1.7
3      2.2
4      0.8
      ... 
916    0.2
917    0.6
918    0.4
919    0.5
920    0.2
Length: 921, dtype: float64
```

Then for each dimension we can construct a simple dataframe from the info, for example for `geo`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({key: val for key, val in data['dimension']['geo']['category'].items()})
    index     label
HU      0   Hungary
PL      1    Poland
SK      2  Slovakia
```

So sorting by column `index` we will have the `label`s in desired order, and ordering those according to `data['id']` we get:

```
>>> dimensions = [pd.DataFrame({
...     key: val for key, val in data['dimension'][dim]['category'].items()
... }).sort_values('index')['label'].values for dim in data['id']]
>>> dimensions
[array(['Monthly rate of change'], dtype=object), array(['All-items HICP'], dtype=object), array(['Hungary', 'Poland', 'Slovakia'], dtype=object), array(['1996M02', '1996M03', '1996M04', '1996M05', '1996M06', '1996M07',
       '1996M08', '1996M09', '1996M10', '1996M11', '1996M12', '1997M01',
       '1997M02', '1997M03', '1997M04', '1997M05', '1997M06', '1997M07',
       '1997M08', '1997M09', '1997M10', '1997M11', '1997M12', '1998M01',
       '1998M02', '1998M03', '1998M04', '1998M05', '1998M06', '1998M07',
       '1998M08', '1998M09', '1998M10', '1998M11', '1998M12', '1999M01',
       '1999M02', '1999M03', '1999M04', '1999M05', '1999M06', '1999M07',
       '1999M08', '1999M09', '1999M10', '1999M11', '1999M12', '2000M01',
       '2000M02', '2000M03', '2000M04', '2000M05', '2000M06', '2000M07',
       '2000M08', '2000M09', '2000M10', '2000M11', '2000M12', '2001M01',
       '2001M02', '2001M03', '2001M04', '2001M05', '2001M06', '2001M07',
       '2001M08', '2001M09', '2001M10', '2001M11', '2001M12', '2002M01',
       '2002M02', '2002M03', '2002M04', '2002M05', '2002M06', '2002M07',
       '2002M08', '2002M09', '2002M10', '2002M11', '2002M12', '2003M01',
       '2003M02', '2003M03', '2003M04', '2003M05', '2003M06', '2003M07',
       '2003M08', '2003M09', '2003M10', '2003M11', '2003M12', '2004M01',
       '2004M02', '2004M03', '2004M04', '2004M05', '2004M06', '2004M07',
       '2004M08', '2004M09', '2004M10', '2004M11', '2004M12', '2005M01',
       '2005M02', '2005M03', '2005M04', '2005M05', '2005M06', '2005M07',
       '2005M08', '2005M09', '2005M10', '2005M11', '2005M12', '2006M01',
       '2006M02', '2006M03', '2006M04', '2006M05', '2006M06', '2006M07',
       '2006M08', '2006M09', '2006M10', '2006M11', '2006M12', '2007M01',
       '2007M02', '2007M03', '2007M04', '2007M05', '2007M06', '2007M07',
       '2007M08', '2007M09', '2007M10', '2007M11', '2007M12', '2008M01',
       '2008M02', '2008M03', '2008M04', '2008M05', '2008M06', '2008M07',
       '2008M08', '2008M09', '2008M10', '2008M11', '2008M12', '2009M01',
       '2009M02', '2009M03', '2009M04', '2009M05', '2009M06', '2009M07',
       '2009M08', '2009M09', '2009M10', '2009M11', '2009M12', '2010M01',
       '2010M02', '2010M03', '2010M04', '2010M05', '2010M06', '2010M07',
       '2010M08', '2010M09', '2010M10', '2010M11', '2010M12', '2011M01',
       '2011M02', '2011M03', '2011M04', '2011M05', '2011M06', '2011M07',
       '2011M08', '2011M09', '2011M10', '2011M11', '2011M12', '2012M01',
       '2012M02', '2012M03', '2012M04', '2012M05', '2012M06', '2012M07',
       '2012M08', '2012M09', '2012M10', '2012M11', '2012M12', '2013M01',
       '2013M02', '2013M03', '2013M04', '2013M05', '2013M06', '2013M07',
       '2013M08', '2013M09', '2013M10', '2013M11', '2013M12', '2014M01',
       '2014M02', '2014M03', '2014M04', '2014M05', '2014M06', '2014M07',
       '2014M08', '2014M09', '2014M10', '2014M11', '2014M12', '2015M01',
       '2015M02', '2015M03', '2015M04', '2015M05', '2015M06', '2015M07',
       '2015M08', '2015M09', '2015M10', '2015M11', '2015M12', '2016M01',
       '2016M02', '2016M03', '2016M04', '2016M05', '2016M06', '2016M07',
       '2016M08', '2016M09', '2016M10', '2016M11', '2016M12', '2017M01',
       '2017M02', '2017M03', '2017M04', '2017M05', '2017M06', '2017M07',
       '2017M08', '2017M09', '2017M10', '2017M11', '2017M12', '2018M01',
       '2018M02', '2018M03', '2018M04', '2018M05', '2018M06', '2018M07',
       '2018M08', '2018M09', '2018M10', '2018M11', '2018M12', '2019M01',
       '2019M02', '2019M03', '2019M04', '2019M05', '2019M06', '2019M07',
       '2019M08', '2019M09', '2019M10', '2019M11', '2019M12', '2020M01',
       '2020M02', '2020M03', '2020M04', '2020M05', '2020M06', '2020M07',
       '2020M08', '2020M09', '2020M10', '2020M11', '2020M12', '2021M01',
       '2021M02', '2021M03', '2021M04', '2021M05', '2021M06', '2021M07',
       '2021M08'], dtype=object)]
```

Now simply use this to define the index of your data and you’re done:

```
>>> val.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(dimensions, names=data['id'])
>>> val
unit                    coicop          geo       time
Monthly rate of change  All-items HICP  Hungary   1996M02    2.4
                                                  1996M03    1.6
                                                  1996M04    1.7
                                                  1996M05    2.2
                                                  1996M06    0.8
                                                            ... 
                                        Slovakia  2021M04    0.2
                                                  2021M05    0.6
                                                  2021M06    0.4
                                                  2021M07    0.5
                                                  2021M08    0.2
Length: 921, dtype: float64
```

Now with `stack` and `unstack` you can pivot dimensions as you wish:

```
>>> val.unstack('geo')
geo                                            Hungary  Poland  Slovakia
unit                   coicop         time                              
Monthly rate of change All-items HICP 1996M02      2.4     1.4       0.3
                                      1996M03      1.6     1.6       0.2
                                      1996M04      1.7     2.0       0.3
                                      1996M05      2.2     1.3       0.5
                                      1996M06      0.8     0.9       0.2
...                                                ...     ...       ...
                                      2021M04      0.8     0.7       0.2
                                      2021M05      0.6     0.4       0.6
                                      2021M06      0.4     0.1       0.4
                                      2021M07      0.6     0.4       0.5
                                      2021M08      0.2     0.3       0.2

[307 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! This is the first time I'm getting data like this, but I will learn from this!

Comment: One question, I need to transform this dataframe, but I'm not sure what are the column and row names since it's more dimensional. How could I do the normal DF transformation on this one? (change data types, rename columns, etc.)

Comment: @JoshBob You have 2 index levels that have a single value so you could drop those. With `val.unstack('geo').droplevel(['unit', 'coicop'])` you have a more traditional dataframe with mono-dimensional columns and index.

Comment: Ah, that will be helpful, thank you! @cimbali